# Separate tooltips in composed charts using Recharts

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, recharts

I was trying for a solution to get separate tooltips for each charts in composed charts. This is a sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-composed-chart-h9zif
Here I would like to see individual tooltips on however for all the datapoints. I did try for custom tooltips but I dont think it worked as expected.

Please help me with some solution.

Thanks in advance,
Madhura Sajjan